# Cannot install py2exe with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am trying to install [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org). I have Python 2.7 installed on my machine. Their [website](http://www.py2exe.org/old/) mentions that they have released support for 2.7, but when I try to install, it mentions that Python Version 2.6 required, which was not found in the registry. I have downloaded py2exe-0.6.9.

Any one else come up with this problem and figured out how to solve it?

Comment: I hope you have found a solution since then! I would be great to know what that was!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe/download). It's py2exe for Python 2.7.

Comment: Here's the link for x64 version: http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe/download

Comment: If any one faces registry issue with 64 bit, use 32 bit one, mentioned in Rod answer, it works fine in those cases.

Comment: This made no difference.